# Printing more than 3 factors in r table

Tags: r, r-factor

I have 2 factor variables and 1 Logical variable in my R dataframe :

```
> table(eaos$GM, eaos$CONTRACTOR.FLAG)

                                  N    Y
  Belfast                      1145    0
  East Anglia                  7969  207
  London                       7583  232
  North East                   8378  113
  North Wales & North Midlands 9852   91
  North West                   8124  130
  Province                     1128    0
  Scotland                     7804  105
  South East                   7309  115
  South Wales & South Midlands 6991  140
  Unkn                           20    0
  Wessex                       8116  209
```

The above table shows my business units and whether any contractors were working in that patch.

The 3rd column looks like this:

```
> table(eaos$GM,eaos$EARLY)

                               FALSE TRUE
  Belfast                        458   31
  East Anglia                   1810  268
  London                        2074  338
  North East                    2437  467
  North Wales & North Midlands  2177  415
  North West                    1461  347
  Province                       447   41
  Scotland                      1352  278
  South East                    1460  292
  South Wales & South Midlands  1707  315
  Unkn                             2    0
  Wessex                        2042  301
```

This table shows if the engineer arrived on site early or not.
I want to print to find out if the contractor.flag was yes and he/she arrived early or not in the following format:

```
> table(eaos$GM,eaos$EARLY)

                               TRUE   Contractor.FLAG
  Belfast                       31           0
  East Anglia                   268          110
  London                        338          210
  North East                    467          100
  North Wales & North Midlands  415          90
  North West                    347          100
  Province                      41           0
  Scotland                      278          101
  South East                    292          110
  South Wales & South Midlands  315          130
  Unkn                          0              0
  Wessex                        301          209
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: like a flat table? `with(mtcars, ftable(am, vs, gear))` What's the expected output?

Comment: I have given the expected output in the last table. (Had to type in myself)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to print with ftable as suggested by rawr

```
> ftable(eaos$GM,eaos$EARLY, eaos$CONTRACTOR.FLAG)
                                       N    Y

Belfast                      FALSE   458    0
                             TRUE     31    0
East Anglia                  FALSE  1717   93
                             TRUE    267    1
London                       FALSE  1991   83
                             TRUE    335    3
North East                   FALSE  2377   60
                             TRUE    466    1
North Wales & North Midlands FALSE  2133   44
                             TRUE    411    4
North West                   FALSE  1410   51
                             TRUE    346    1
Province                     FALSE   447    0
                             TRUE     41    0
Scotland                     FALSE  1299   53
                             TRUE    275    3
South East                   FALSE  1417   43
                             TRUE    289    3
South Wales & South Midlands FALSE  1647   60
                             TRUE    314    1
Unkn                         FALSE     2    0
                             TRUE      0    0
Wessex                       FALSE  1926  116
                             TRUE    295    6
```

This breaks down per GM patch. Checks if the arrived early (True/False) and check the Contractor Flag (N/Y)